# key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "tigera-operator": current value is "default"

Tags: kubernetes, helm

when I am trying to install calico using helm 3 like this:

```
helm install calico projectcalico/tigera-operator --version v3.26.1 --namespace tigera-operator
```

shows error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: Installation "default" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "tigera-operator": current value is "default"
```

I have delete all resouce about calico, this is the helm list view:

```
> helm list --all-namespaces

WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/config
NAME                        NAMESPACE           REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION
apollo                      reddwarf-storage    1           2021-08-05 18:21:38.258357 +0800 CST    deployed    mysql-8.8.2             8.0.26
apollo-portal               sre                 1           2021-08-05 22:40:46.426948304 +0800 CST deployed    apollo-portal-0.2.2     1.8.2
apollo-service-dev          sre                 1           2021-08-05 22:08:38.710129289 +0800 CST deployed    apollo-service-0.2.2    1.8.2
apollo-service-pro          sre                 1           2021-08-06 12:27:27.715893028 +0800 CST deployed    apollo-service-0.2.2    1.8.2
cruise-redis                reddwarf-cache      1           2021-08-05 13:26:25.890924 +0800 CST    deployed    redis-14.8.8            6.2.5
grafana-1660569230          reddwarf-monitor    1           2022-08-15 21:13:54.733182 +0800 CST    deployed    grafana-8.1.0           9.0.7
kube-prometheus-1660560589  reddwarf-monitor    1           2022-08-15 18:50:49.022506 +0800 CST    deployed    kube-prometheus-8.0.15  0.58.0
reddwarf-postgresql         reddwarf-storage    1           2021-08-05 13:29:02.970051 +0800 CST    deployed    postgresql-10.9.1       11.12.0
reddwarf-redis              reddwarf-cache      1           2023-04-10 22:02:36.26849 +0800 CST     deployed    redis-17.8.0            7.0.8
traefik                     default             1           2021-08-03 21:54:28.952288144 +0800 CST deployed    traefik-10.1.1          2.4.9
traffic-manager             ambassador          1           2023-03-06 02:12:34.761128 +0800 CST    deployed    telepresence-2.11.1     2.11.1
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to install the calico smoothly? I have tried to delete the namespace and recreate it but still did not work. This is how I delete the namespace:

```
namespace=tigera-operator && kubectl get ns $namespace  -o json | jq '.spec.finalizers = []' | kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/$namespace/finalize" -f -
```